# Is there an existing class which can serve as a /dev/null equivalent of a ByteBuffer?

Tags: java, io, nio

I've looked at extending ByteBuffer, but that requires some pretty ugly hacks.

Extending the implementations like DirectByteBuffer looks sloppy as well, since I would be allocating a lot of resources that aren't actually used.

Is there an good existing solution to allocate a ByteBuffer where all writes are completed (but the values discarded), and all reads return 0? I havent seen anything in the JDK, but maybe someone knows of a third party code snippet that works well, that's ideally platform agnostic.

Comment: I was actually looking for a similar solution for this.  You can't extend `ByteBuffer` because of the package-private constructors, and my solution is just going to be composition.  Why exactly do you want to be able to write to a buffer but not read from it?  We might be able to provide you with a better solution if we know what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: The use case is complicated, and I could probably write some code in the containing class to get around the requirement, but it would add more complexity to an already complex class.

Essentially, I have a stream of data coming in, and occasionally need to consume that data while not actually processing it (since it will be expired). I could write code to achieve the same by using a normal ByteBuffer and doing a .clear() but it would be messier.

Comment: Most likely using a ByteBuffer and calling clear() as needed is the simplest solution.

Comment: What data type holds the data that comes in?

Comment: The class is a ByteBuffer multiplexer / demultiplexer. There are several other ByteBuffers that exist to hold data before/after processing. When a specific band gets closed, the data may still come in for some time afterward, and there needs to be a black hole for that data to go into.

It sounds like I may end up just writing more code to do a .clear() after every read/write, since I do have a boolean that keeps track of the active/inactive state of each band.